# How to fix "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY"?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm sending an HTTP request using Retrofit 2, I've done everything regularly, however, the situation is "not standard". I have a problem that one of the objects to receive in the response class is once sent as an object and in the other as a list. So I don't know whether to initialize it in the response class as an object or as an array.

> **Here is my full JSON response:**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Smith",
            "nicname": "Joe",
            "age": "32",
            "description": "Example",
            "state": "Nevada",
            "city": "Las Vegas",
            "job": "Security",
            "adress": "Some adress 1",
            "postcode": "412421",
            "details": {
                "intro": {
                    "title": "Mr.",
                      "married": "No",
                    "children": "2"
                },
                "rest": {
                    "pitctures":"24",
                    "chats": "7",
                    "lastChat": "12-01-2016",
                    "lastVisited": "07-04-2017",
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "Smith",
            "nicname": "Joe",
            "age": "32",
            "description": "Example",
            "state": "Nevada",
            "city": "Las Vegas",
            "job": "Security",
            "adress": "Some adress 1",
            "postcode": "412421",
            "details": {
                "intro": {
                    "title": "Mr.",
                      "married": "No",
                    "children": "No"
                },
                "rest": []
            }
        }
    ],
    "errors": false,
    "update_notifications": {
        "message": [],
        "friend_request": [],
        "code": "IzS0hivN1cyHBdygpeWv"
    }
}
```

> **Details.java class:**

```
public class Details {

    @SerializedName("intro")
    @Expose
    private Intro intro;
    @SerializedName("rest")
    @Expose
    private Rest restObject;

    private ArrayList<Rest> restList;

    public Details(Intro intro, Rest restObject) {
        this.intro = intro;
        this.restObject = restObject;
    }

    public Details(Intro intro, ArrayList<Rest> restList) {
        this.intro = intro;
        this.restList = restList;
    }

    public Intro getIntro() {
        return intro;
    }

    public void setIntro(Intro intro) {
        this.intro = intro;
    }

    public Rest getRestObject() {
        return restObject;
    }

    public void setRestObject(Rest restObject) {
        this.restObject = restObject;
    }

    public ArrayList<Rest> getRestList() {
        return restList;
    }

    public void setRestList(ArrayList<Rest> restList) {
        this.restList = restList;
    }
}
```

> **And here is my CustomDeserializer.java** *(rest array neeed to be empty, maybe that's a problem)* **based on @Farid's answer:**

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Details> {

    @Override
    public Details deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject detailsObject = json.getAsJsonObject().get("details").getAsJsonObject();
        Details details;

        JsonObject introObject = detailsObject.get("intro").getAsJsonObject();
        String title = introObject.get("title").getAsString();
        String married = introObject.get("married").getAsString();
        String children = introObject.get("children").getAsString();

        try {
            JsonObject restObject = detailsObject.get("rest").getAsJsonObject();

            String pitctures = restObject.get("pitctures ").getAsString();
            String chats = restObject.get("chats ").getAsString();
            String lastChat = restObject.get("lastChat ").getAsString();
            String lastVisited = restObject.get("lastVisited ").getAsString();

            details = new Details(new Intro(title, married, children),
                      new Rest(pitctures, chats, lastChat, lastVisited));
        }catch (IllegalStateException e){
            JsonArray restArray = detailsObject.get("rest").getAsJsonArray();
            ArrayList<Rest> restList = new ArrayList<>();
            details = new Details(new Intro(title, married, children), restList);
        }
        return details;
    }
}
```

> **In MainActivity based on @Farid's answer:**

```
Gson gsonConverter = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Details.class, new CustomDeserializer()).create();


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(myUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonConverter))
                .build();

        service1 = retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait!");
        progressDialog.show();

        final MyRequest myRequest = new MyRequest();

        myRequest.setPin(pin);

        final Call<MyResponse> myResponseCall = service1.get (code, myRequest);

        myResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. You'll have to create a custom Deserializer. As you can see there is `JsonDeserializer<Details>` whose type parameter is `Details` that means any time GSON tries to deserialize `Details` object, it will call `CustomDeserializer` to deserialize it. Anything inside `Details` object should be deserialized manually as seen in the `CustomDeserializer` class whereas all other types outside `Details` class (e.g. Class, String, int) will be handled by GSON seamlessly

> CustomDeserializer.java

```
    public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Details> {

    @Override
    public Details deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject detailsObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        Details details;
        Intro intro = new Intro(detailsObject.get("intro").getAsJsonObject().get("example").getAsString());

        try {
            JsonObject restObject = detailsObject.get("rest").getAsJsonObject();
            String example = restObject.get("example").getAsString();

            details = new Details(intro, new Rest(example));
        }catch (IllegalStateException e){ // In case rest is ArrayList
            JsonArray restArray = detailsObject.get("rest").getAsJsonArray();
            ArrayList<Rest> resList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (JsonElement element: restArray){
                JsonObject restObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
                String example = restObject.get("example").getAsString();
                resList.add(new Rest(example));
            }

            details = new Details(intro, resList);
        }

        return details;
    }
}
```

Then you have to register `CustomDeserializer` as `TypeAdapter` as below:

```
 Gson gsonConverter = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Details::class.java,
 CustomDeserializer()).create();

 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonConverter))
 ///Rest of Retrofit builder code
```

If you want to know more about custom deserialization, search for "gson deserialization" and find a tutorial that appeals to you most.

---

### Below code snippets are OP specific classes

> Response.java

```
public class Response {

    private List<DataItem> data = null;
    private Boolean errors;
    private String example;

    public List<DataItem> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<DataItem> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Boolean getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(Boolean errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public String getExample() {
        return example;
    }

    public void setExample(String example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

}
```

> Data.java

```
 public class DataItem { 
    private String example;
    private Details details;

    public String getExample() {
        return example;
    }

    public void setExample(String example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

    public Details getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}
```

> Details.java

```
public class Details {

    private Intro intro;
    private Rest restObject;
    private ArrayList<Rest> restList;

    public Details(Intro intro, ArrayList<Rest> restList) {
        this.intro = intro;
        this.restList = restList;
    }

    public Details(Intro intro, Rest restObject) {
        this.intro = intro;
        this.restObject = restObject;
    }

    public Rest getRestObject() {
        return restObject;
    }

    public ArrayList<Rest> getRestList() {
        return restList;
    }

    public Intro getIntro() {
        return intro;
    }

    public void setIntro(Intro intro) {
        this.intro = intro;
    }
}
```

> Intro.java

```
public class Intro {

    public Intro(String example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

    private String example;

    public String getExample() {
        return example;
    }

    public void setExample(String example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

}
```

> Rest.java

```
public class Rest {
    private String example;

    public Rest(String example) {
        this.example = example;
    }

    public String getExample() {
        return example;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but nothing happened, maybe because of my response don't only contain details but also others classes?

Comment: This won't work for your specific case, I just replicated JSON you've posted. You have to create classes and field types based on the JSON response you're receiving. If you post your response from server excluding sensitive info, I might propose a specific solution for your case

Comment: Of course, I corrected everything to be my own example, I posted the above answer new so if you can look

Comment: Edited first post

Comment: Check edited answer, as I don't know what is inside your `"rest":[]` ArrayList, I just thought it's a list or `Rest` objects. If it holds some other information then you'll have to edit `catch (IllegalStateException e){}` block to meet your needs.

Comment: To your first question: Even if you have different type of classes `CustomDeserializer` will only be called when it sees an object with `Details` type. Other types (Class, String, int) will be deserialized out-of-the-box. I mean anything inside `Details` should be manually deserialized and anything outside `Details` will be deserialized automatically.

Comment: I did everything you said and it doesn't work again

Comment: Then either there is something wrong in your implementation or JSON you've provided in your question is different from the server's response. I can only help if you provide accurate information. By the way, the JSON object in your question is malformed. You can't have `=` to denote value it should be `:` instead, I had to refactor it. If you're getting the exact same response from the server, then backend developers should refactor the JSON.

Comment: Can I somehow send you private message?

Comment: Sure, no problem. You can write to me in about 3 hours. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5636313/farid

Comment: Thank you, when I try to debug, nothing happens, no errors but nothing happens

Comment: Can you see your response from server with Retrofit? I mean are you using `Httplogginginterceptor`?

Comment: No, I can't, the request is not sent... I don't know... 
Did you see the whole code I inserted above?

Comment: Check message, please.

Comment: Farid can you check message?

Comment: I wrote to you in the messages

Comment: @Niklaus, I wrote to you in the messages

Comment: Farid check message pls

Comment: @Niklaus, I'm there